# At Least One input must required in DIV jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form in which there are 5 inputs

I need to check From their inputs at least one must be fill on Button Click using JQuery.

```
<div id='myForm'>
    <input name="baz" type="text" />
    <input name="bat" type="text" />
    <input name="bab" type="text" />
    <select name="foo">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="bar">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
     <input type='button' value='submit' onclick='return chk();'/>
</div>

<script>
         function chk()
         {
               // i need to check here
                  alert('i wan to to check it here')
         }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for this requirement?

Comment: This must be one of the most commom questions on stackoverflow. Please do some research or even some basic googling. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[value="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($('input, select').not('[type="button"]').filter(function() {
     return this.value.trim()!="";
      }).length) {
        alert('valid');
           //$("#myForm").submit()
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Tcg3U/5/)

Comment: Yeah, looked like a form, but it was just a div with a regular button?

Answer (score 4):

```
(function() {
   var valid = false;

   $('#myForm').submit(function(evt) {   

      $(this).find('input[type="text"], select').each(function() {
         if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            valid = true;
         }
      });

      if (!valid) { 
          evt.preventDefault(); 
         /* stop form submission (and tell the user to fill at
          * least one field 
          */ 
      }
   });
}());
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tcg3U/3/

Comment: i need it on button click.. can you please check again question i updated it

Comment: thanks calderan but i need on button click not on form submit. please check my question i updated it

Comment: @samirprogrammer dude.. this code work on the click of your button only.. it is binded to the submit behavior of your form. This is better way of handling it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YdA6D/ check out this one... it's easier to understand but basically we both have the save logic.

Comment: furthermore you should try to focus especially on the logic behind the control of your inputs and adapt it to your existant code.

Comment: thanks saurabh it is working but there is not other better way what if i have 20 or more inputs??